# Importing external libraries in ride/robotframework

Tags: python-2.7, robotframework

I was writing test cases using robot framework. i use ride that is a GUI toolkit to create and run test cases using robotframework. Now i need to import external libraries (RequestsLibrary) with my test suite. I was unable to import the RequestsLibrary.

I tried pip install -u robotframework-requestslibrary but in vain. 
Then i downloaded the zipped file from the link https://github.com/bulkan/robotframework-requests. unzipped the link and then ran python setup.py install but still unable to import the library.
Also the external library is placed in the python path which for me is
/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages.

Can anyone suggest as to where am i going wrong?

Comment: i have searched extensively on the net and found to try this out , still this gives me the same error.

Comment: python libdoc.py --format RequestsLibrary /usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/RequestsLibrary/RequestsKeywords.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "libdoc.py", line 120, in <module>
    from robot.utils import Application, seq2str
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-packages/robotide/lib/robot/__init__.py", line 22, in <module>
    from robot.rebot import rebot, rebot_cli
  File "/usr/local/lib/python2.7/site-

Comment: Did setup.py work? Did if fail? If it failed, what was the error? If it succeeded, what does "still unable to import the library" mean? Did you get an error? What error?

Answer (score 0):

I would split the problem in two:

1. install the library you need on your machine and check you can import them from Python
2. import this library from a Robot Framework

To install the library you should be able to do it with "pip". Maybe you could try to install "[requests](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/latest/)" first. If it works, then try "robotframework-requests" which is just a layer on the top of requests. Once pip install goes without error, check from a Python Shell if you do "import requests" or "import robotframework-requests" to see if everything is well installed and python path ok.

Then, to import from Robot Framework, you could try first without RIDE. Just create a simple Robot Test as a text file and do a "library  requests" or "library  robotframework-requests" to import the library in your test. If the test runs OK, then try it again but this time from RIDE.

If you follow those steps, you should be able to see at what stage the problem occurs. It is not clear in your message when you get the error.

Finnaly, if you want to do some REST tests from Robot Framework, you might want to take a look at a [short blog post I wrote on this topic](http://laurent.bristiel.com/robot-framework-rest-and-json/).

Answer (score 0):

> I tried pip install -u robotframework-requestslibrary but in vain.

The name of the package is `robotframeworks-requests`. Try this:

```
$ pip install -u robotframework-requests
```

If that doesn't help, describe what "in vain" means. Did it silently fail? Did it fail with an error message? What was the error message?

Answer (score 0):

I had the same issue, that was solved installing the **requests** library (pip install -U requests), as recommended by Laurent.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know why, but it's working fine for me :

1 - pip install -U Requests
2 - pip install -U RequestsLibrary